# is it possible to modify identify columns start with value in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

I have a table rss_sub_source, and the id as a identify column. Now I want to modify the start with value(I forget to define the start with value when I added identify column). I have tried this way:

```
ALTER TABLE rss_sub_source 
    ALTER id SET NOT NULL,  -- optional
    ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
        (START WITH 1233);
```

shows this column already as a identify column. Then I modify the SQL like that:

```
ALTER TABLE rss_sub_source 
    ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS 
        (START WITH 1233);
```

did not work shows `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 74`. What should I do to make it work? This command still not work:

```
 ALTER TABLE rss_sub_source 
    ALTER id START WITH 1233;
```

this is my table create command:

```
-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.rss_sub_source;

CREATE TABLE public.rss_sub_source (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    sub_url varchar NOT NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT date_part('epoch'::text, now()),
    updated_time bigserial NOT NULL,
    sub_status int2 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    rss_type varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    standard_type varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'RSS'::character varying,
    standard_version varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'rss20'::character varying,
    cron varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT '0 */1 * * * *'::character varying,
    trigger_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    next_trigger_time timestamp NULL,
    sub_name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    last_trigger_time timestamptz NULL,
    tags _int4 NULL,
    source_url varchar(256) NULL,
    sub_type varchar NULL,
    intro varchar NULL,
    remark varchar NULL,
    title_hash varchar NULL,
    failed_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    lang varchar NULL,
    frequency_month int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    reputation int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    rep_lastest_refresh_time int8 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    scrapy_take_time int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    follower int8 NULL,
    censor_status int4 NULL DEFAULT 1,
    etag varchar(64) NULL,
    last_modified varchar(32) NULL,
    editor_pick int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    fav_icon_url varchar(128) NULL,
    dynamic_interval int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    local_icon_url varchar(256) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rss_sub_source_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_sub_url UNIQUE (sub_url)
);
```

the table already have 1232 rows. I am using this command to modify the start with value:

```
ALTER TABLE rss_sub_source 
ALTER id SET START WITH 1233;
```

it execute success but seems not work. How to check the table primary key current start with value?When I am using this command to check the current seed value of id:

```
select CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.rss_sub_source', 'id'))
```

shows greater than 1200. But when I insert a new sql in my app, still get a small seed id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setval()` to change the current value of the underlying sequence.

To get the sequence's name use `pg_get_serial_sequence()`

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.rss_sub_source', 'id'), 1234);
```

or more dynamic:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.rss_sub_source', 'id'), max(id))
from public.rss_sub_source;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5db48ab4a308d6a3e534ee4a2c32c8d5)

Comment: Seems did not work, it always start by 30+ when I insert a new row after change the sequence value@a_horse_with_no_name by the way the id is not serial but identify in new PostgreSQL feature

Comment: `pg_get_serial_sequence()` works with `identity` columns just as well. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5db48ab4a308d6a3e534ee4a2c32c8d5

Comment: I do not know why when I insert a new row, it still get a id 38 that the database not used, I want to get an id greater than 1234. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Dolphin https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9628e8cf2bec9b67a5ea8dbf19504a1